# NDSolve returns only a trivial solution

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to numerically solve the following differential equation

```
Clear[wmax, g, G, wsol]
wmax = 0.726714;         (* define me please *)
{tinf, tmax} = {0.05, 2.05}; (* define me as well please *)

g[t_] := 
  func[t]; (* give me the full version or a standalone toy-version \
instead *)

G[t_] := (t - tinf)/(tmax - tinf)

wsol = NDSolve[{
        w'[t]==Sqrt[2/(G[w[t]]*(1 - G[w[t]])) Integrate[g[x](1-x),{x,w[t],w[tmax]}]], 
        w[tmax] == wmax}, 
        w, {t,tinf,tmax}]
```

where `G` is a cdf, for instance `G[t]=(t-tinf)/(tmax-tinf)` and the boundary value `wmax` is given (equal to `0.726714` with a uniform distribution on [2,4] for `G`).

`NDSolve` always returns the trivial solution `w[t]=w[tmax]`. I am certain that there exists other solutions with a strictly positive derivative, but I cannot find a way to obtain them.

I have tried with the `Shooting` option but unsuccessfully so far, partly because I don't understand the syntax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

**Edit**: Here is the code I'm using. Thanks for your input! PS: I take a uniform distribution on [0,csup] for G here. My goal is to test different distributions.

```
    Clear["Global`*"];
    Clear[\[Theta], w, c0, k, G, g, \[Theta]sup, \[Theta]inf, x, y, \[Lambda], \[Eta], \[Mu], Q0, Q1, Qfb, Qm, csup, wtilde, temp, wm];

    Qfb[\[Theta]_] := \[Theta] - c0;
    Qm[\[Theta]_] := 2 \[Theta] - \[Theta]sup - c0;
    \[Theta]inf = 3;
    \[Theta]sup = 4;

    G[t_] := t/csup;
    g[t_] = D[G[t], t];
    csup = 2;

    c0 = 1;
    k = 1;
    wm = x /. Solve[c0*k == x + G[x]/g[x], x][[1]] // FullSimplify

    (* assumptions that must be satisfied *)
    c0*k < csup
    \[Theta]inf - c0 >= k
    2*\[Theta]inf - \[Theta]sup - c0 >= 0
    wm < c0*k
    wm > 0

(*Step 1: computation of the boundary value w[\[Theta]sup] through an indepedent requirement*)

    Clear[\[Mu], sol\[Mu]];

    \[Mu][w_, w\[Theta]sup_] := Sqrt[2 G[w]*(1 - G[w])*
    Integrate[g[wtilde] (c0*k - wtilde), {wtilde, w, w\[Theta]sup}]];
    
    sol\[Mu] = Solve[\[Mu][w, w\[Theta]sup] == (\[Theta]sup - \[Theta]inf)*G[w], w];

    wnot[w\[Theta]sup_] = w /. sol\[Mu][[2]][[1]];

    Clear[temp0];
    \[Mu][wtilde_, w\[Theta]sup_] = Sqrt[2 G[wtilde]*(1 - G[wtilde])*Integrate[g[x] (c0*k - x), {x, wtilde, w\[Theta]sup}]];

    temp0[w\[Theta]sup_?NumericQ] := (\[Theta]sup - \[Theta]inf) -NIntegrate[(G[wtilde]*(1 - G[wtilde]))/\[Mu][wtilde, w\[Theta]sup], {wtilde, wnot[w\[Theta]sup], w\[Theta]sup}];

    w\[Theta]supsol = w\[Theta]sup /. FindRoot[temp0[w\[Theta]sup], {w\[Theta]sup, wm}]

(*Out: w[\[Theta]sup]=0.726714*)

(*Step 2: computing w[\[Theta]]*)

    wsol = NDSolve[{w'[\[Theta]] == Sqrt[2/(G[w[\[Theta]]]*(1 - G[w[\[Theta]]])) Integrate[g[wtilde] (c0*k - wtilde), {wtilde, w[\[Theta]], w\[Theta]supsol}]], w[\[Theta]sup] == w\[Theta]supsol}, w, {\[Theta], \[Theta]inf, \[Theta]sup}]

(*Out: I always end up with the trivial solution w[\[Theta]]=w[\[Theta]sup]. But others should exist...*)
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the non-trivial solution by lowering the boundary value by a small amount:

```
    wsol = NDSolve[{w'[\[Theta]] == Sqrt[2/(G[w[\[Theta]]]*(1 - G[w[\[Theta]]])) Integrate[g[wtilde] (c0*k - wtilde), {wtilde, w[\[Theta]], w\[Theta]supsol}]], w[\[Theta]sup] == w\[Theta]supsol-10^(-10)}, w, {\[Theta], \[Theta]inf, \[Theta]sup}]
```

This generates a unique strictly increasing solution, as expected.

Comment: It's great that you managed to resolve your own issue. As it currently stands though, this is not in a format of a fully-fledged answer. Please, take a moment to edit appropriately and show your work as other might also benefit from this post in the future. Remember, that you can accept your own answer if it solves the issue in a satisfactory way!

Comment: Done, many thanks!